# Dropzone accepted files and maxFiles

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I am trying the Dropzone plugin for the first time to use as a music upload option.

My code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".dropzone").dropzone({
        url: '<?= base_url(); ?>entry/upload/<?= $entry_number; ?>',
        acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png",
        width: '100%',
        height: 100,
        maxFiles: 1,
        params:{
            'action': 'save'
        },
        success: function(res, index){
            $('#reload_details').trigger('submit');
        }
    });
})
```

The problem I have is that I can still upload multiple files and I can upload files of any type, and not the ones I entered under `acceptedFiles`.

I have also tried using the following:

```
accept: function(file, done) {

    var extension = file.name.substr( (file.name.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );

    if (extension == "jepg" || extension == "png") {
        done();
    }
    else { 
        done("Naha, you don't."); 
    }
},
```

I believe I might be missing something small, but I cannot find a solution and have read through many similar questions.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly you need to either use `acceptedFiles` with file extensions (.jpg, .xlsx)

-or-

`acceptedMimeTypes` with the sort of MIME types in your current code.

Comment: I did try `acceptedFiles: ".jpeg, .png",` now, but still the same result

Comment: The above still did not work for me, for now I used php to check before the upload, but will have a look again at the JS solution